# Как сделать прогресс бар для Ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

Как сделать прогресс бар для Ajax-запроса? Не gif-изображение, а именно отслеживать загрузку страницы, которая загружается через Ajax-запрос.

Comment: Это очень и очень "не точная наука"  - погрешностей будет много )

Comment: когда начинается загрузка пускаем програсс-бар с ограничителем, т.е. с 0% до 88% (примерно), когда аякс выполняется дополняем оставшиеся проценты. Так?

Comment: Я реализовал так http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/php/ajax-progress-php-script-
without-polling/